# Xamarin.Forms Migration to AndroidX: Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 is using Java.Interop.JavaLibraryReferenceAttribute

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am currently migrating a Xamarin.Forms project to Xamarin.Forms 5 and AndroidX. I get the following errors and don't really have any idea how to fix them. I removed all support library Nuget packages and replaced them with AndroidX.

Maybe it comes from an external dependency which still uses the old support library, but how do I find out which one it is? There are hundreds of dependencies. The error message is not precise enough.

[image]

Comment: If error persists after updating all the package to the latest , I think you have to go through  the dependencies of the plugins one by one , yes this is not a easy work ..

Comment: It is very strange. When I click "Rebuild all" the mentioned errors occur, but when I start debugging in the Android emulator (Build + Launch emulator + Launch app) it seems to work.